# "Noscript" Shows Raw HTML when the Page is Reloaded without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, noscript

I have a pop up message that tells the user when JavaScript is disabled.  The problem is happening in **Chrome**.

Here's the site with just my `<noscript>`: [Cloud9 Website](https://c9.io/bionicrm/demo-project/workspace/test.html).  It's blank if you have JavaScript enabled.  Here's how to duplicate my experience:

1. View the blank page.
2. Disable JavaScript.
3. Reload the page.

You should be able to see the raw HTML that's inside the `<noscript>`.  If you reload the page again, then the proper message pops up.

I also tested this locally with XAMPP: same thing.

This is my HTML:

```
<noscript>
    <div class="nojs">This website requires JavaScript to run.&#160; Please<a href="activatejs.php"class="link" target="_blank">enable it</a> or use a web browser that supports JavaScript.</div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Here's a [Chromium bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=232410&q=noscript%20reload&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) for this issue.

Comment: Do you know how often Chrome is updated for bug fixes?  I see that the issue was reported on April 17th.

Comment: They prioritize, and this is sort of an annoyance that can happen in this unusual circumstance, but it's not a critical issue, so don't hold your breath. One thing you could do would be to put a very visible HTML comment above the rest of the HTML instructing Chrome users that if they can see the message, it's a bug in Chrome, and they should refresh their browser. Also, "star" that but report if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 0):

While this is a bug, you could use this work around:

```
<div class="nojs"><noscript>This website requires JavaScript to run. Please </noscript><a href="activatejs.php"class="link" target="_blank"><noscript>enable it</noscript></a><noscript> or use a web browser that supports JavaScript.</noscript></div>
```